# C++ Operator overloading using pointers to class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, operators, overloading

This is my class:

```
class B : public A{
private:
double r;


public:
B(){};
B(double x_, double y_, double r_){
    x1 = x_; y1 = y_; r = r_;
};
~B(){};
B operator+(const B&  other)
{
    double result_r = r + other.r;
    return B(x1, y1, result_r);
}
B operator*(const B&  other)
{
    double result_r = this->r * other.r;
    return B(x1, y1, result_r);
}
int operator<(const B&  other){
    if (this->r<other.r)return 1; else return 0;
}
int operator>(const B&  other){
    if (this->r>other.r)return 1; else return 0;
}
};
```

class A is abstract, this is how i declare B:

```
A*a = new B(10, 10, 10);
A*b = new B(20, 20, 20);
```

while something like `(a<b)` does work, `A*c=a+b;` does not work.
it does work if i dont use pointers to A, and < has int as type, so i assume its something with the type the overload returns and i jsut cant figure out how to do it, is there even a way?

Comment: Indent your code. Then say what do you mean with it does not work? A logical error or a syntax one for example.

Comment: Too much effort to begin sentences with capital letters and use punctuation and spelling? It's like you got really tired half way through writing this.

Comment: sorry, it just returns these errors in visual 2013 `error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers` and `IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type 
`

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> while something like `(a<b`) does work, `A*c=a+b;` does not work.

`(a<b)` works because the compiler knows how to compare two pointers. It doesn't mean that it's going resolve to `bool B::operator<(const B&)`.

`A*c=a+b;` does not work because the compiler does not now how to add two `B*` objects.

To use the operator overload functions you have defined, you have to use objects of type `B` not pointers to the objects of type `B`.

You can explicitly call the operator functions by using:

```
B* b1Ptr = new B;
B* b2Ptr = new B;
B b3 = b1Ptr->operator+(*b2Ptr);
```

But that's not what you are going to get by using

```
B b3 = b1Ptr + b2Ptr;
```

You can also use:

```
B b3 = *b1Ptr + *b2Ptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

`A* c` declares a pointer. The result of `a+b` is of type `B`. So the compiler tells you that you cannot assign an object of type `B` to a pointer. Why do you need pointers?

Use simply `A c = a + b`.

If you really want to use a pointer, do

```
A tmp = a + b;
A* c = &tmp;
```

or directly

```
A* c = new B(a+b);
```